# Update value in a column from another worksheet depending on the date in a range

Tags: excel, vba

Update value in a column from another worksheet depending on the date in a range

Our new pay system at work went live in August 2017.

This is the new pay calendar (called Pay Periods)

Start Date  End Date    Pay period

10 Aug 17   23 Aug 17   PP0001

24 Aug 17   06 Sep 17   PP0002

07 Sep 17   20 Sep 17   PP0003

21 Sep 17   04 Oct 17   PP0004

05 Oct 17   18 Oct 17   PP0005

19 Oct 17   01 Nov 17   PP0006

This is the table for members (called MemberList)

Name    Due Date    Amount  Processed in Pay Cal

Raghu   15 Jul 17   $248.00 PP0001

Vima    20 Jul 17   $354.00 PP0001

Abhi    10 Aug 17   $954.00 PP0001

Neelima 23 Aug 17   $134.00 PP0001

Raghu   14 Sep 17   $134.00 PP0003

Vima    21 Sep 17   $524.00 PP0004

Abhi    06 Oct 17   $332.00 PP0005

Neelima 20 Oct17    $158.00 PP0006

Raghu   06 Sep16    $456.00 PP0002

Vima    19 Sep 17   $159.00 PP0003

Abhi    03 Oct 17   $357.00 PP0004

Neelima 18 Oct 17   $852.00 PP0005

I want to update the Processed in Pay Cal column with the pay periods.

Anything with a due date on or 23 AUG 17 to be processed in PP0001 and the rest of the appropriate pay calendar. I need help with the code to write a macro.

Pseudo code:

```
Sub updateColunm4()

If duedate <= 23Aug17 then

    Update column 4 to PP0001

Else

    Update column 4 to the appropriate pay period

End if

End Sub
```

Thank you

Regards

Raghu

Comment: You don't need vba for this. You can use If or possible a lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an UDF you can use. You can run the test procedure to see the result, if your data is set-up as in attached image. Or simply deploy udf direct.

It's signature is

```
GetPayPeriod(dueDate, lookupTable)
```

The function name is `GetPayPeriod` which you call from in the cell by putting

```
=GetPayPeriod(dueDate, lookupTable)
```

`dueDate` is the date for which you want the pay period. `lookupTable` is the range to look in.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim lookupTable As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") 'change as appropriate
Set lookupTable = ws.Range("A2:C7")

Dim dueDate As Date

dueDate = ws.Range("B15").Value2

MsgBox GetPayPeriod(dueDate, lookupTable)

End Sub

Public Function GetPayPeriod(ByVal dueDate As Date, ByVal lookupTable As Range) As String

If dueDate <= 42970 Then '23rd Aug 17
    GetPayPeriod = "PP0001"
    Exit Function
End If

Dim payPeriodsArray()

payPeriodsArray = lookupTable

Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(payPeriodsArray, 1) To UBound(payPeriodsArray, 1)

   If dueDate >= payPeriodsArray(i, 1) And dueDate <= payPeriodsArray(i, 2) Then

        GetPayPeriod = payPeriodsArray(i, 3)
        Exit Function

   End If

Next i

GetPayPeriod = "Period not found"

End Function
```

Example usage in the sheet:

[image: Usage in sheet]

Comment: A big thank you to everyone who replied. I am a novice at VBA and have to learn things. At 57 trying to learn a new thing takes a bit longer.

Comment: Absolute pleasure

Comment: QHarr could you attach the file you worked on? I am trying to make the code work, no luck.

If you could attach the file, it would be much appreciated. Or you can email me to my Gmail account. The Gmail id is raghu.prabhu[at]
gmail.com

Thank you.

Comment: you should be cautious of downloading files with code in from internet. You are safer asking for an xlsx and code separately with some description of how they go together. This is to stop malicious code infecting your system. That said, here is the file link: https://ufile.io/js8xv

Comment: Hi QHarr,

How do I use this? As I said, in sheet1 there are four columns name, duedate and amounts. The fourth column is blank.

I have over 3000 lines, so how do I use "=GetPayPeriod" when I am inputting the data through a form.

Thank you.

I am a novice. So these silly questions.

Comment: Hiya: There was no mention of a form in your original question. You have a number of options. You can use the code to complete the fourth column entry for your form  as part of the form code; manually put UDF in sheet or adapt the code to populate the fourth column. This really becomes a new question and not really something I can easily put in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I consider this to be solved.

Comment: Oops! I did not know what I was doing.